# Find the convergence region of the improper integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{x^a}{1+x^a}dx$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> Find the convergence region of the improper integral 
>   $$\int_1^\infty \frac{x^a}{1+x^a}dx\,.$$

To find the convergence region of this integral, it is equivalent to find the convergence region of the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^a}{1+n^a}\,.$$

I use the ratio test and root test but could find the convergence area for $a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral is convergent for $-a \gt 1$ or $a\lt-1$ and otherwise it is divergent.

Comment: I divide $n^a$ on both denominator and nominator. Then I get $\frac{1}{n^{-a}+1}$. Then how do you see that $-a>1$?

Comment: @Kenneth.K Note that $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac {dx}{x^p}$ converges for $p\gt1$

Comment: I get $\frac{1}{n^{-a}}>\frac{1}{n^{-a}+1}>\frac{1}{(n+1)^{-a}}$. Therefore, $-a>1$ iff the integral is convergent?